# how to check status in if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to check the status which is come from a model in the form 0 and 1 but I have to show 0 as a enable and 1 as a disable but don't know how to use if below code

```
@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#role-table').DataTable({
          serverSide: true,
          processing: true,
          responsive: true,
          ajax: '{{ route("admin.role.getRoleList") }}',
          columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id',className:'text-center' },
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'status', name: 'status' },
            { data: 'action', name: 'action', classrole: 'text-center', orderable: false }
          ],
          stateSave: true
        });
      });
    </script>
    @endpush
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For formatting your `status` column, use this:

```
 {
    data: 'status',
    name: 'status',
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
       return  data?$'<span> disable </span>':'<span> enable </span>';
    }
 }
```

Note that you have the power to use HTML tags for formatting your data columns.

For more information visit [DataTable Renders](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers)

Answer (score 0):

Write your yajra datatables query like this:

```
return datatables()->of($model) 
->editColumn('status', function ($query) {
    if($query->status == 0)
    {
        return 'enable';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'disable';
    }
})
->escapeColumns([])
->make(true);
```